# LINQPAD - PredicateBuilder throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

When I run the statement below in Linqpad it's throwing the following error:

```
The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

This seems to match some of the other examples I've seen online.  What am I doing wrong?

LinqPad version 5

Language: C# Statement

Connection: C# project DLL containing Entity Framework

```
var dynamicGlobalFilter = PredicateBuilder.True<users>();
dynamicGlobalFilter = dynamicGlobalFilter.And(x => x.username.Contains("w"));

var test = users.Where(dynamicGlobalFilter);
test.Dump();
```

NOTE:
I've included PredicateBuilder in Linqpad by pressing F4 in my query window and checking the box.

**UPDATE (FIX!):**

1. Press F4 in your query window in LINQPAD
2. Under Additional References press ADD
3. Click Browse
4. Locate the LinqKit.dll on disk (downloaded at the LinqKit website)..if you've made it this far you should already have it in your .NET solution
5. Click OK
6. Click on the Additional Namespace Imports tab
7. Click Pick From Assemblies link
8. Select LinqKit.dll and then Select the Namespace
9. Click Add Selected Namespace
10. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

Please add .AsExpandable()

```
var dynamicGlobalFilter = PredicateBuilder.True<users>();
dynamicGlobalFilter = dynamicGlobalFilter.And(x => x.username.Contains("w"))
var test = users.AsExpandable().Where(dynamicGlobalFilter);
test.Dump();
```

To read more please see reference at 
[Albahari.com Predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

> "Entity Framework's query processing pipeline cannot handle invocation expressions, which is why you need to call AsExpandable on the first object in the query. By calling AsExpandable, you activate LINQKit's expression visitor class which substitutes invocation expressions with simpler constructs that Entity Framework can understand."

Comment: `AsExpandable()` is only needed if you are going to put a user-defined function in the query.

Comment: I duplicated the code in LinqPad  along with the error. By adding .AsExpandable()  the correct results were returned for the condition

Comment: I ran the code without `AsExpandable` on a SQL database without issue once a reference to PredicateBuilder was added to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you would be better off adding the latest LINQKit from NuGet.

Press `F4`, click the `Add NuGet...` button, search for LINQKit and select either LINQKit or LINQKit.Core and click the `Add To Query` button, the select LINQKit in the Add Namespaces dialog and click the `Add selected namespaces in future without asking` button, then click the `OK` button, then click the `Close` button, then click the `OK` button.

This gets you the latest LINQKit enhancements, including a `New` operator that handles `And`s and `Or`s automatically:

```
var dynamicGlobalFilter = PredicateBuilder.New<users>();
dynamicGlobalFilter = dynamicGlobalFilter.And(x => x.username.Contains("w"));

var test = users.Where(dynamicGlobalFilter);
test.Dump();
```

Note: If you wanted to use the older version, you could just press `F4` and click the `Include PredicateBuilder` checkbox in the lower right hand then click the `OK` button.